# Display DIV According to Time

Tags: php

I need to display a "Live News" div based on the time. The div will only say "watch the news" and be a link to the news site. Here is the div:

```
<div class="live-news">Watch the Live News</div>
```

Here are the times:

```
Mon - Fri
430am - 8am
noon - 1
5pm - 6:30pm
11 - 11:30pm

Saturday 
7-830am
5-6pm
630-7pm
11-1130pm

Sunday
6-7am
5-6pm
630-7pm
11-12am
```

How would I build the array and then pick from the array to display the element?

******* UPDATED FOR PHP *******

Please help!

Comment: It will be smarter to do it with PHP. No client browser errors, less browser load, you deliver only content that you should, less page loading time, etc.

Comment: What is news source and type ? Seems more sensible to use ajax and filter source. Can run ajax on periodic interval

Comment: The question of server vs client-side is completely dependent on your requirements. If the display is dependent on the user locale, then it may better to do it on the client, unless you wish to implement the detection of the users locale in the PHP script. It also depends on any front-end frameworks you may be using. If no frameworks, then I would just default to PHP/server side.

Comment: I think you're right. Any suggestions @YasenZhelev?

Comment: @Josh this is for a news web site based in seattle. So the times are pacific, and they'll always be that way. This site uses wordpress.

Comment: @charlietfl this div will ONLY say "breaking news" - not pulling in any actual news. It'll just be a link to the simulcast of the news on a different site.

Comment: This sounds like an [X Y Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) then. Update question with higher level objective/display criteria

Comment: @charlietfl The objective is to display an element on the page during only specific times, which I have noted above. How can I do this?

Comment: days of week also have index 0-6. Build an array that has time ranges in it for each day and use day index to do look up. Run your hide/show code in an interval timer

Comment: @Sam Luedke actually Josh is right. If you want to display the div based on the local time of the user, you will have to detect it one way or another. If you want to display it based on the your server time (for example) or specific time zone, then go with the server side.

Comment: @YasenZhelev yes - I am going to do it server side with PHP, thanks so much for your insight, I appreciate it. It looks like I need to build an array with the times, and then do an 'if' to see what the time is and if its 'x' time, display the element.

Comment: UPDATED - question only referring to PHP now

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do that on the server use that.

```
$week_day = date('w');
$current_time = date('Hi');

$show_news_div = false;
if ($week_day >= 1 && $week_day <= 5)
{
  if (($current_time >= '0430' && $current_time <= '0800') || ($current_time >= '1200' && $current_time <= '1300') || ($current_time >= '1700' && $current_time <= '1830') || ($current_time >= '2300' && $current_time <= '2330'))
  {
    $show_news_div = true;
  }
}
if ($week_day == 6)
{
  if (($current_time >= '0700' && $current_time <= '0830') || ($current_time >= '1700' && $current_time <= '1800') || ($current_time >= '1830' && $current_time <= '1900') || ($current_time >= '2300' && $current_time <= '2330'))
  {
    $show_news_div = true;
  }
}

if ($week_day == 0)
{
  if (($current_time >= '0600' && $current_time <= '0700') || ($current_time >= '1700' && $current_time <= '1800') || ($current_time >= '1830' && $current_time <= '1900') || ($current_time >= '2300' && $current_time <= '2359'))
  {
    $show_news_div = true;
  }
}

if ($show_news_div)
{
  ?>
  <div class="live-news">Watch the Live News</div>
  <?php
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Yasen! I almost have this working. I have the div displaying, but the function for the times is not. It just displays all the time.

Comment: @Sam Luedke what do you mean by saying 'function for the times is not'?

Comment: I used the code you put up. The div displays but NOT based on the time's set in the function. Make sense?

Comment: @Sam Luedke I tested it and it worked for me. Try manually setting $week_day and $current_time to test different days and times.

Comment: I tried that. No go. Maybe its something to do with this:

if ($display)
            {
              ?>
                <div class="live-news"><a href="http://www.kirotv.com/videos/news/kiro-newscast-hd2/vCYwYn/" target="_blank">Breaking News</a></div>
              <?php
            }

does that need an 'else'? I can't figure it out.